# Metaprogramming Ruby: Using a specific superclass constructor

Tags: ruby, inheritance, constructor, metaprogramming

In Ruby I would like to use a specific constructor of a superclass in a subclass. I want to do it because I have manipulated the superclass constructor dynamically. The corresponding subclass is dynamically created too.

I've already found a way to do it, but as I am not very familiar with Ruby Metaprogramming I wonder if there is a better way of doing it.

The following are my classes and my current solution. Thanks for reading and thinking :)

```
class A < Object
  def self.new *args
    super
    #doing things
  end
end

class B < A
  def self.new *args
    #doing things
    return superclass.superclass.method(:new).unbind.bind(self).call(args)
  end
end
```

Comment: This code gives me a `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)` error under 1.9.

Comment: hm... its running fine for me on 1.9.2 I can run both A.new and B.new in irb as well as in a script.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the exact same code you've got in this question?

Comment: Double checked it by copying the code from the question with two editors and it worked with both. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: At the very least, I can show it doesn't work in 1.8.6: http://codepad.org/4WYIf6Nb

Comment: It turns out it works in 1.9.2 after all. Must be something different between 1.9.1 (the version on my computer) and 1.9.2. http://ideone.com/BPKQC

Comment: I've got it. Its the args collection. In <1.9.2 it seems to be necessary to pass it like this: ...bind(self).call(*args). Still not sure why :)